# How to create an array of pandas dataframe in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code. In which CROPS & CITY are lists contains names of crops and cities in the dataframe named df. I want to divide my single dataframe 'df' into multiple dataframes for each crops and city value. and want to store them in dataframes array for that what I should put in place of XYZ?

```
for crop in CROPS:
  for city in CITY:

    XYZ = df.loc[(df['Commodity.Name'] == 'crops') & (df['City.Name'] == 'city')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare an empty list outside of the loop and keep on appending the filtered `DataFrame`s to the list, like:

```
list_of_filtered_df = []
for crop in CROPS:
  for city in CITY:
    list_of_filtered_df.append(df.loc[(df['Commodity.Name'] == 'crops') & (df['City.Name'] == 'city')])
```

`list_of_filtered` contains the filtered `DataFrame`s.

Comment: Yes, I used same concept of dictionary just used dictionary[crop + '_' + city] = .....